# Asset pipeline only works with application.js

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

This works:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

By works I mean it loads all the `js` files in the tree because `application.js` contains `require_tree .`

But then I do this:

```
mv application.js login.js
```

and update the tag to

```
<asset:javascript src="login.js"/>
```

and no js gets loaded to my page.

It is like the tag looks only for `application.js`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Strange, whts the relative path of the application.js from project root dir ? btw you dont need to specify ".js" extension, asset tag can figure i tout

Comment: @sudhir the path is `grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: it seems to work if i put `<asset:javascript src="login.js"/>` at the end of the `<body>`

Comment: Are you sure you have layoutHead tag in your layout (main.gsp) ? Verify it.